# Photos are recoverable but videos are not on my vivo x27 phone

Tags: mobile, data-recovery

In order to test data recovery apps, I have conducted experiments where I took photos and videos, deleted them permanently, then attempted to recover them immediately. The photos can be recovered perfectly, but the videos can not be recovered at all. I've repeated these experiments for days and this problem occurs consistently. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it because my [vivo x27 phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/vivo_x27-9629.php) is not rooted properly so the recovery apps can't function properly?

Comment: What apps? What do their documentation say? I'm not sure that you have provided enough info.

Comment: Disk digger. It tells me "internal memory undetected, please make sure device is rooted properly". I also deleted my old videos and it fails to recover any of them as well. So the key is to evelate permission level I think but I already turned on developer mode and I don't how to root properly

Comment: "The free version of DiskDigger can recover photos and videos only (recovering videos requires your device to be rooted)." - are you using the free version?